# Gimp: How to create

Tags: gimp

I'm working on a website design in gimp. I really love the figures and math equations at University of Iowa's stats website (http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/). I would like to create something like this, perhaps do handrawn equations and figures and scan it in.

Once I have the appropriate image, how could I turn it into a transparent image that I can overlay onto a header (in gimp)?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at how they do it. It's just a transparent image with semi-transparent diagrams on it: http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/sites/all/themes/stat/img/header2.png

Comment: Yes, but I am a noobie to gimp, can you point me towards a tutorial for making "transparent image with semi-transparent diagrams" Or what keywords to search for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would scan some diagrams and handwritten math equations . Then I would open it from gimp.  After you done it you can go to --> colours and use Desaturate.  You can use any method  from there. There are only 3. See which one looks the best on your photo. After you got black and white photo go to colours and choose --> Posterise and use it with level set to 2. After this you go to --> Layers --> Transparency and choose Colours to Alpha. Choose white to remove the background. After this save you image as . png file. You should scan possible black and white image. You can write some diagrams on white paper without lines of print some diagrams and math equation. If you got scanner you can also set the settings to scann only in two colours and then you do not have to use Desaturation. I hope this will help you.